# Where should I add subviews into scrollview within a custom UIView subclass, when I use Auto-layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a custom`UIView` subclass here(which is `self` here), and it uses Autolayout and Size class(wAny hAny) in the storyboard.

Also, there is a`UIScrollView` in it and 6 `UIImageViews` in the`UIScrollView` as its paging content.

In order to get the correct width of `self`(320 pt but not the default width 600 or 568 in storyboard), I have to set the frame of`UIImageView` in `layoutSubviews`, but it causes infinite loop here.

On the other hand, if I add imageViews in`awakeFromNib`, it gets the incorrect width of `self` which is 584(600-16).

Where should I add subviews (6 imageViews) to the scrollView to avoid infinite loop ?

```
#define Self_Width CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)
#define Self_Height CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)
@interface YSAdScrollView ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property(nonatomic) NSArray *coverAdImages;
@property(nonatomic) UIScrollView *ysCoverAdScrollView;

@end

@implementation YSAdScrollView



-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self addSubview:self.ysCoverAdScrollView];
    self.ysCoverAdScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(Self_Width * self.coverAdImages.count , Self_Height);

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[ysCoverAdScrollView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[ysCoverAdScrollView(106)]->=0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:self.viewsDictionary]];


    [self.coverAdImages enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *imageName, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, idx * Self_Width, Self_Height)];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        imageView.layer.borderWidth =1 ;
        NSLog(@"imageView[%d] = %@" , (int)idx , NSStringFromCGRect(imageView.frame));
        [self.ysCoverAdScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }];
}

-(UIScrollView *)ysCoverAdScrollView{
    if (!_ysCoverAdScrollView) {
        self.ysCoverAdScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]
                                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];

        self.ysCoverAdScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;   
    }
    return _ysCoverAdScrollView;
}

-(NSArray *)coverAdImages{
    if (!_coverAdImages) {
        _coverAdImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"coverAd4.jpg",@"coverAd1.jpg",@"coverAd2.jpg",@"coverAd3.jpg",@"coverAd4.jpg",@"coverAd1.jpg", nil];
    }
    return _coverAdImages;
}
```

Comment: layout is for layout - that is, sizing and positioning. You should create your views somewhere else (such as in viewDidLoad:)

Comment: You need to add [imageView layoutIfNeeded] after adding it to scrollView.